# Javascript page scrolls automatically up and down

Tags: javascript, loops, scroll, infinite-loop, infinite-scroll

I'm struggling with a challenge that is just a bit out of my skill range. I'm trying to make a page scroll (very slowly) up and down on an infinite loop. I got the code to loop once, but my challenge is to make it loop over and over again. I would love advice.

```js
do {
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 2650}, 57820);
  
});

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 35000);
  
});
}
while (true === true);
```

Comment: This is a great attempt, but you might have already noticed if you try to run this code it will lock up your browser. That's the whole infinite loop thing going on. So rather then using a `do...while` loop you should consider using an interval timer. You can learn more about that [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: It does lock up my browser. Yeah, I think I once heard that infinite loops can cause problems. I'm going to look into that link. Thank you!

Comment: I followed the link you provided and it helped a lot. Unfortunately, then I ran into another problem, but the code another user provided solved it. I'm grateful you provided this link because even though my code wasn't perfect, it still worked and I was the one who wrote it. Made me feel like I'm getting batter.

Comment: Great news! Glad to help. Stick with it - just takes practice. Have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript code is mainly [asynchronous](https://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/#:%7E:text=Asynchronous%20code%20takes%20statements%20outside,console.). What this means for you is that the browser is running the "go to top" and "go to bottom" code rapidly. And thus crashes your browser. What you want, is to wait till the scroll to bottom is completed, then scroll to top. Here is an example that does what you want.

```js
// Getting a reference to html. The way you did it in the loop
// is slow because it has to get access to it every time.
const main = $('html');

// The scrollTop function
// scrolls to the top
function scrollTop() {
    console.log('scrolling to top')
    main.animate({scrollTop: 0},1000,"linear",scrollBottom /* this is a callback it means when we are done scrolling to the top, scroll to the bottom */)
}

function scrollBottom() {
    console.log('scrolling to bottom')
    main.animate({scrollTop: document.body.offsetHeight},1000,"linear",scrollTop /* this is a callback it means when we are done scrolling to the bottom, scroll to the top */)
}

// this kicks it off
// again only running $(document).ready once to increase performance.
// Once scrollTop completes, it calls scrollBottom, which in turn calls scrollTop and so on
$(document).ready(scrollTop);
```

Comment: This worked great! And it's very simple, actually. I appreciate that your code is so clean. I've only started learning javascript and I get the basic idea, but applying the language to doing specific things like this is still beyond me. I can learn from what you wrote

Comment: If you think my answer solves the problem, could you please accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Just did! Sorry, I'm new. I didn't realize what accepting an answer was or that the checkmark was the way to accept. I do appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will not wait until one function is completed so You can't create such loop. But You can utilize jquery.animate complete functionality:

```js
$(document).ready(scrollDown()); //run function first time

function scrollUp() {
 $('body,html').animate({
   scrollTop: 0
 }, 35000, "linear", 
   scrollDown//we are on the top, let's go down 
 );
 return false;
}

function scrollDown() {
 $('body,html').animate({
   scrollTop: $(document).height()
 }, 57820, "linear",
   scrollUp//scrolling down is completed, let's go up
  );
}
```

Here is working example of this code: https://jsfiddle.net/y7fguk52/